How to set catalog and database with pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.config (databricks)
I want to create a spark session w/ pyspark and update the session's catalog and database using the spark config, is this possible?
Using config isn't working
I tried to update the catalog and session using pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.config(), but it doesn't work. No changes appear to be registered.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("config_test") \
    .config(map={"spark.sql.defaultCatalog": "test_catalog", "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.defaultDatabase": "test_db"}) \
    .getOrCreate()
spark.catalog.currentCatalog() #returns "hive_metastore"
spark.catalog.currentDatabase() #returns "default"

Using session.catalog does work
The code below updates the catalog and database the way I'm wanting to, but I'd like to do that through the spark config if it's possible.
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("without_config_test") \
    .getOrCreate()
spark.catalog.setCurrentCatalog("test_catalog")
spark.catalog.setCurrentDatabase("test_db")
spark.catalog.currentCatalog() #returns "test_catalog"
spark.catalog.currentDatabase() #returns "test_db"

Below is a screen shot from databricks showing the issue there, I'm using version 15.4 LTS w/ Spark 3.5.0:


I have tried the same approach like you:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("config_test") \
    .config(map={"spark.sql.defaultCatalog": "dbrx02", "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.defaultDatabase": "test_db"}) \
    .getOrCreate()
spark.catalog.currentCatalog() #returns "hive_metastore"
spark.catalog.currentDatabase()

Results:

'default'


The catalog is usually initialized before the configurations from .config() are fully applied.
This means the default catalog (usually hive_metastore) is loaded and becomes the active catalog before any custom settings can take effect.
The reason is map keyword is not required and incorrectly formats the configuration settings.

I have tried the below:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("configcatalog") \
    .config("spark.sql.defaultCatalog", "dbrx02") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.dbrx02.defaultDatabase", "dbo2") \
    .getOrCreate()
print(spark.catalog.currentCatalog())  
print(spark.catalog.currentDatabase())


Results:
dbrx02
default

